# The button value has been changed without permission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

I have a "upload_image_button" and am handling the button in this way:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $( document ).on( 'click', '.upload_image_button', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var uploadButton = $(this)

         mediaUploader = wp.media({
          title: 'Choose Image',
          button: {
          text: 'Choose Image'
        }, multiple: false });

        mediaUploader.on('select', function() {
          var attachment = mediaUploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
          var id = uploadButton.attr('image');
          $('.upload_image_button').parent().children('input').val(attachment.id);
        });

        mediaUploader.open();

    });
});
```

The problem is that when i upload image, the button value is changing to the image url. Im not sure it's changing ?
That''s the button field:

```
<input class="upload_image_button button button-primary" type="button" value="Upload Your Custom Default Image" />
```

Comment: What do you think this line `$('.upload_image_button').parent().children('input').val(attachment.id);` does?

Comment: This line gets me the image id, which i need to use later. Is there any other way to get it ?

Comment: How about storing the value in a variable instead of the button value?

Comment: It will be clearer if you explain it with example

Comment: Get an object's value: `var foo = obj.val();` vs. Set an object's value: `obj.val("new value here");`